# Error in debian installation through USB

Tags: debian, debian-installer

In the process of installing debian 9, I have encountered the following error:

> `Please insert the disc labeled: 'Debian GNU/Linux 9.1.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 NETINST 20170722-11:28' in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press [Enter]`
>   *`Media Change`*

I have been trying to install through Bootable USB.

Below is the image of the error screen:
[image: error screen]

Answer (score 0):

You can try start console manually (**Alt+Ctrl+F2** to start and **Alt+Ctrl+F1** to exit on Debian 9.1) and mount USB flash data to /media/cdrom/ point.

But this is abnormal behaviour i think. May be it is a bug. I have no problem with Debian 9.1 installation to my pc/servers.

Answer (score 0):

During installation you get a prompt to install the softwares not available in installation media. You probably chose yes and it is now asking for a media to install the softwares from.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is due to loose connection between the laptop and the Bootable Pendrive. I restarted the installation placing the Bootable pendrive containing Debian in another USB port and it worked fine. I now have Debian alongside Windows successfully.

Thanks for the help guys.